# Delete all but one duplicate rows in SQLite for version 3.22.0?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm having some issues with deleting the duplicate row with the highest user ID and was wondering how I could achieve this in SQLite with a method that is compatible with version 3.22.0?

I can identify all of the duplicate rows by running this statement:

```
SELECT
    code, issue, COUNT(*)
FROM
    Data
GROUP BY
    code, issue
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) > 1
```

I've tried using:

```
delete from Data t1
where exists (select 1 from Data t2
              where t1.code = t2.code and t1.issue = t2.issue
                and t1.id < t2.id);
```

Which gave me a syntax error near `t1`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use `AS` before t1: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=9c276d9efefbf541a41c4a68cd10da2c

Comment: @forpas I actually tried using ``DELETE FROM Data AS t1. ...`` which threw me a new error that said ``near "AS": syntax error``.

Comment: You can see in the fiddle that it works with AS.

Comment: It's weird since it threw me an error when I tried running it. Perhaps it might be due to versions? I see the fiddle runs on 3.27.0 whereas I'm running on 3.22.0?

Comment: It could be, but consider upgrading. SQLite's newest version is 3.34.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think sqlite do not support alias with `delete`.

Try following query:

```
delete from Data
where exists (select 1 from Data t2
              where data.code = t2.code and data.issue = t2.issue
                and data.id < t2.id);
```

Comment: Thank you! Out of curiosity, would it be possible to optimize this query somehow, as I'm trying to delete around 1.3k rows in a table with 3.5 million rows?

Comment: @Californium . . . This answers the question that you have asked here.  If you want to focus on performance, I would suggest asking a *new* question with appropriate details about data size and so on.